# How to link block level elements in html e-mails?

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, outlook, block

What would be the best way to make a whole block of content clickable in an html email so that it also works in Outlook (2003, 2007, 2010).

For example, I have this Call-To-Action:

[image: call to action button]

So far I've come up with this:

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px #ffffff dashed;">
    <!-- NAVIGATION AREA START -->
    <tr>
      <td width="370" style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size: 22px;font-weight:bold;line-height:52px;">
        <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; height:100%;">
            <a href="http://${servername}/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">
                LEARN MORE ABOUT ABOUT THIS
            </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="160">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="24">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color:#fff; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;width:128px;height:24px;color: #000000;text-decoration: none;font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;">
                        <a href="http://${servername}/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000;margin-left: 5px;">
                            CLICK HERE
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img style="display: block;" width="13" height="24" border="0" alt="" title="" src="http://${servername}/images/mailing/arrow-white.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- NAVIGATION AREA END -->
  </table>
```

The problem is that the whole area within the dashed border should be clickable. I tried wrapping the whole `table` with an `a` tag, but this doesn't work in Outlook or IE (it works in Firefox).

Or, consider this:

```
<table width="255" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="border: 10px solid #fff;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:130px;padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
            <p style="color:#ffffff;font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size: 16px;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <strong>FAQ</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color:#d0d0d0; line-height: 20px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
                Learn more about our services.
            </p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 15px;">
            <p style="margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;">
                <img width="54" height="102" border="0" src="http://${servername}/images/mailing/questionmark.png" title="" alt="">
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here too, the whole block (within the white border) should be clickable, not just the individual lines of text.

How would you go about this, considering the bad support for CSS in Outlook 2007/2010 (e.g. no `display` CSS-property)?

Bottom line: **How to link a block level alement without being able to wrap it with `a` (tried with `table` and `div`) or using `display: block;`?**

Comment: Maybe you can switch to DIV based layout instead of table based layout.

Comment: @Mrchief DIV is not really an option because of the poor support by Outlook 2007/2010. Unless you're saying it would work with DIVs in those clients?

Comment: I don't know much about HTML templates, but there is a good article [here](http://www.thoughtresults.com/html-email-templates)

Comment: @Saeed: Yes, I'm aware of the general limitations for HTML mail templates, thanks for the link though!

Answer (score 5):

This answer will aim to show how all different options render in Outlook (2013), starting with **the "best" solution found so far**:

```
<table width="100%" style="background-color: #ccc;"><tr>
<td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333;">
        Go to some great website!
    </a>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

This will be rendered like this:

[image: link in email, best version found]

Or, with the link hitbox annotated:

[image: link in email, annotated best version]

Yeah, that sucks: you want the entire block to be clickable. Basically I'm here to tell you that **the answer to the question "*how to link block elements (outlook-compatible)*" is: this is not possible, not without workarounds.**

---

To support my claim (PS. I *highly* welcome anyone proving this claim wrong!), here's all the variations I've tried, with their respective renderings in Outlook. I've tried to include some solutions suggested in other answers too.

Here's the code I've used to generate e-mails:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My e-mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="660px" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 660px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 15px;">

                    <p>1. The "best" text-only version I've found:</p>
                    <table width="100%" style="background-color: #ccc;"><tr>
                    <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;">
                        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333;">
                            Go to some great website!
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    </tr></table>

                    <hr />
                    <p>2a. Workaround using an image. Setting size through style attribute does not work.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
                        <img alt="Go to some great website!" src="your custom image" style="width: 100%; height: 30px;" />
                    </a>

                    <hr />
                    <p>2b. Workaround using an image. Kind of works, but requires an image of exactly correct size through attributes.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
                        <img alt="Go to some great website!" src="your custom image" width="640px" height="30px" />
                    </a>

                    <hr />
                    <p>3. Attempt to link the entire table. Does not work.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333;">
                        <table width="100%" style="background-color: #ccc;"><tr>
                        <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;">
                                Go to some great website!
                        </td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </a>

                    <hr />
                    <p>5. Attempt to link the entire div. Does not work.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333;">
                        <div style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 15px; text-align: center;">
                            Go to some great website!
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <hr />
                    <p>6. Setting anchor tag to display as a block. Does not work.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style=" display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; background-color: #ccc; padding: 15px; text-align: center;">
                        Go to some great website!
                    </a>

                    <hr />
                    <p>6. Hacking with line-height, does not work.</p>
                    <div style="background-color: #ccc; text-align: center;">
                        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="line-height: 3em; text-decoration: none; color: #333;">
                            <span style="vertical-align: middle;">Go to some great website!</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's how they're rendered by Outlook 2013, annotated with the link hitbox:

[image: renderings by outlook of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Put an `<a>` in each of the fields. Not elegant, but this works.

If there is a field that is empty, just put a transparent image in there that's the right width and height. (image itself, not resized in html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd add the call to action as an image in the email and simply wrap it with an anchor tag.

```
<a href="//"><img src="http://myimage.com/image.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Given that this is for an email, is there a reason you want to build up the call-to-action in HTML?

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gv5aZ/

(Quick fiddle i've put together for you)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use an image there because the text is flexible and generated out of the CMS.

Comment: Thanks, but as I've mentioned, unfortunately Outlook 07/10 doesn't support `display`. See here: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this extensively but I did manage to get something working.

In you header styles and in the 'a href=""' add the below:

Header style:

```
#outlook a { padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; }
```

Link inline style:

```
<a style="font-family: #; font-size: #px; text-decoration: #; border: #color #px #; color: #; padding-bottom: #px; padding-top: #px; padding-left: #px; display: inline-block; padding-right: #px; font-style: #;" href="#" target="_blank">Read more...</a>
```

Replace # with your styles of course except for the display property (leave that one in!)

Again, I haven't tested this extensively but for me it worked so don't miss anything out from what I've written here :)

EDIT: You might not have a border in your design so make it the same colour as your background

Comment: Have you tested it with Outlook 2007/2010? As I've mentioned in my OP the `display`property is not supported in that client. Unfortunately I currently don't have Outlook, so can't test your suggestion.

Comment: I haven't fully tested this in your situation, in fact this may not even be a correct answer... My code allows a link to act as a block element (sort of) - Whether or not this works when wrapping around a table I'm not sure - I will test at some point and report back

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just put an anchor around the table? Not entirely sure if it works in outlook though, but it's the easiest solution

```
<a href="...."><table>....</table></a>
```

Comment: That's why that was the first thing that came to my mind. But as alreaady said in my original post:
I tried wrapping the whole `table` with an `a` tag, but this doesn't work in Outlook or IE (it works in Firefox).

Comment: I didn't try that. But I'm thinking, Outlook doesn't like block level elements inside an `a` tag. Indeed, the XHTML specification doesn't allow it.