# HTML email design - Alternatives to putting an <a> tag around a <table>

Tags: html, email, html-table, outlook, hyperlink

This question is very similar to [How to link block level elements in html e-mails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613985/how-to-link-block-level-elements-in-html-e-mails), but that question is quite old and the solutions provided didn't fit my use-case. I'm working on an email template that shows a row of items each kept within a table with multiple rows. Each of the gray boxes is its own table.

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" style="table-layout:fixed; width:800px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f3f3f3; border-color: #cfcfcf; vertical-align: top; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px">
            <table cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; vertical-align: top; height: 35px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> Item 1 </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; height: 150px"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.isdntek.com/gif/polaroid140.gif" style="height: 10px;" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> $9.99 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 bids </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 watchers </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: #f3f3f3; border-color: #cfcfcf; vertical-align: top; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px">
            <table cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; vertical-align: top; height: 35px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> Item 2 </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; height: 150px"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.isdntek.com/gif/polaroid140.gif" style="height: 50px;" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> $9.99 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 bids </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 watchers </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: #f3f3f3; border-color: #cfcfcf; vertical-align: top; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px">
            <table cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; vertical-align: top; height: 35px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> Item 3 </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; height: 150px"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.isdntek.com/gif/polaroid140.gif" style="height: 100px;" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> $9.99 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 bids </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 watchers </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: #f3f3f3; border-color: #cfcfcf; vertical-align: top; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px">
            <table cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; vertical-align: top; height: 35px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> Item 4 </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color: #525252; height: 150px"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.isdntek.com/gif/polaroid140.gif" style="height: 140px;" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> $9.99 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 bids </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 20 watchers </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGosL.png)

Right now I have two anchor tags that link to the same place - one over the item title and one over the item image. I'm trying to reduce the number of links inside the email, so ideally I'd be able to place an anchor tag over the entire table and have the whole gray box be clickable.

Unfortunately, as mentioned in the SO post linked above, putting an anchor tag around a block element is not supported in email clients like Outlook. If you do that, nothing is clickable.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/referabuyer/7v2w4akz/6/) is a JS Fiddle with code snippets for:

1. Our original design with 2 links for each item.
2. The ideal design has an anchor tag around the whole table, but it is unusable due to Outlook.
3. A failed attempt to use span elements with br elements to maintain the look of the original.

If I can recreate the original design with inline elements I'd be willing to try that, but each item has a dynamic title and image, so I think I have to use fixed heights to make everything line up correctly.

If anyone has any advice or techniques, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an onclick to the table like this

```
<table onclick="location.href='your location'">

<table onclick="window.location.href='your location'">
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the `onclick` handlers seem to be stripped out of certain email clients like Gmail, so the table wasn't clickable.